# LDFlex filter by type

Tags: linked-data

I'd like to use [LDFlex](https://github.com/LDflex/LDflex) to list all subjects within a document, of a certain type.

`data["https://example.com/mydocument.ttl"].subjects` provides all the subjects in the document. It's possible in SPARQL to specify something like  `WHERE {?s a mytype}`; how can I do that in LDFlex? Is it possible?

Comment: It seems that there is `sort`, but there is no `filter` in LDFlex expressions: https://github.com/LDflex/LDflex/issues/40

Comment: Ahh, nice issue find. I'd noted sort, maybe it's possible to extend the SPARQL generation in a similar way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `rdf:type` property mapped as a reverse property in your JSON-LD context (let's say, as `ofType`), then you can do the following:

```
data["https://example.com/mydocument.ttl"].ofType(namedNode(myType))
```

where `myType` is the URI of the type.

The implementation was added by https://github.com/LDflex/LDflex/issues/40, and is available as of LDflex v2.8.

Comment: Using LDflex v2.15.2 I get the following error: `Error: Specifying fixed values is not allowed here`. Is it still possible to use this solution? I tried with `publicTypeIndex.subjects.ofType(namedNode("http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms#TypeRegistration"))` but I get the same error.